# Attempting To getElementById within a form

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to make an etch sketch game. I am almost complete and have a clear button, a random grid generator button, and an input field to make an NxN grid. I put these 2 buttons and the input field into a single form and the input field no longer works. The clear button and random grid generator still work. I moved them all into the same form to style them with CSS and would like to leave them in the form if possible. I can not figure out why my input field no longer works but everything else does.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="JS.js" defer></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Etch A Sketch</h1>
        <form id="inputForm">
           <button id="clear">Clear</button>
           <button id="generator">Random Grid</button>
           <input type="number" id="number" min=1 max=64 placeholder="Enter a # 1-64">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="gridContainer">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
//Grabs the form where are of this is housed

var form = document.getElementById("inputForm");
var clearButton = document.getElementById("clear");
var input = document.getElementById("number");

//Starts function that does everything

form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {

//Prevents browser from refreshing on submit

    e.preventDefault();

input.disabled = true;
var boxInput = input.value;
var gridContainer = document.getElementById("gridContainer");
console.log(boxInput);

for (var i = 0; i <= boxInput * boxInput - 1; i++) {

//Creates a certain number of rows and columns based on user input

    gridContainer.style.gridTemplateColumns =  `repeat(${boxInput}, 1fr)`;
    gridContainer.style.gridTemplateRows =  `repeat(${boxInput}, 1fr)`;
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    console.log(div);
    div.className = "grid";
    gridContainer.appendChild(div);
}
});


//If you click on random grid it will create a grid between 1-64

var randomGrid = document.getElementById('generator')
randomGrid.addEventListener('click', function(){
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (65 - 1) + 1); 
console.log(randomNumber);

for (var i = 0; i <= randomNumber * randomNumber - 1; i++) {

    gridContainer.style.gridTemplateColumns =  `repeat(${randomNumber}, 1fr)`;
    gridContainer.style.gridTemplateRows =  `repeat(${randomNumber}, 1fr)`;
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    console.log(div);
    div.className = "grid";
    gridContainer.appendChild(div);
    input.disabled = true;
}
});

//Makes it blue if you mouseover 

gridContainer.addEventListener('mouseover', function(element) {
    if (element.target.classList.contains('grid')) {
        element.target.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    }
});

//Clears grid when clicked on

clearButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   input.disabled = false;
   input.value = '';
   var divs = gridContainer.getElementsByClassName('grid');
   while (divs.length > 0) {
    gridContainer.removeChild(divs[0]);
   }
});
```

Comment: What errors do you get in your console?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify type attribute in the button element because it's inside
the form element.
Because type is not specified it's calling form's onsubmit method by default.
The [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) says

> **formmethod**...
> If the button is a submit button (it's inside/associated with a `<form>` and doesn't have `type="button"`), this attribute specifies the
> HTTP method used to submit the form.

```
<button type="button" id="clear">Clear</button>
<button type="button" id="generator">Random Grid</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need the form, just listen to the input

```js
input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if(e.key === 'Enter') {
    input.disabled = true;
    var boxInput = input.value;
    var gridContainer = document.getElementById("gridContainer");
    console.log(boxInput);

    for (var i = 0; i <= boxInput * boxInput - 1; i++) {
      //Creates a certain number of rows and columns based on user input
      gridContainer.style.gridTemplateColumns =  `repeat(${boxInput}, 1fr)`;
      gridContainer.style.gridTemplateRows =  `repeat(${boxInput}, 1fr)`;
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      console.log(div);
      div.className = "grid";
      gridContainer.appendChild(div);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).